# Twig ternary not applying filter if false

Tags: twig

When using Twig's ternary operator, everything goes as expected EXCEPT the `|raw` filter is not being applied when the condition is false:

```
{{ thing.description|length > 255 ? thing.description|striptags|slice(0,255) ~ '...' : thing.description|raw }}
```

When true, it IS applying the `|striptags|slice(0,255)` filters.

The `|raw` filter does get applied when coded like this (and false):

```
{% if thing.description|length > 255 %}
    {{ thing.description|striptags|slice(0,255) ~ '...' }}
{% else %}
    {{ thing.description|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why `|raw` isn't applied when using ternary syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In fact `|raw` do nothing. Really. Look at its code here.](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Escaper.php#L103-111)

When you do operation, value is marked as **unsafe**. `|raw` mark it as **safe**. If you try to print unsafe value with `{{ ... }}`, it will be escaped. It's how Twig is designed.

Let's analyse that simple code: `{{ (a|raw) ~ (b|raw) }}`

1. `a` is marked as safe.
2. `b` is marked as safe.
3. `a` and `b` are glued together. It's marked as unsafe, because `~` is a operation.
4. Value `a ~ b` is printed **ESCAPED**. Wow.

You must use `{{ (a ~ b)|raw }}`.

In your problem: first you calculate `thing.description|raw` and then it's passed to ternary. Results are marked as unsafe, because ternary is operation. You must use `|raw` after all operations, so `{% if %}` is the only solution.